# Tagging a HBase Table using Spark RDD in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, rdd

I am trying add an extra "tag" column to an Hbase table. Tagging is done on the basis of words present in the rows of the table. Say for example, If "Dark" appears in a certain row, then its tag will be added as "Horror". I have read all the rows from the table in a spark RDD and have matched them with words based on which we would tag. A snippet to code looks like this:

```
var hBaseRDD2=sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf,classOf[TableInputFormat],classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])
val transformedRDD = hBaseRDD2.map(tuple => {
             (Bytes.toString(tuple._2.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("Moviesdata"),Bytes.toBytes("MovieName"))),
             Bytes.toString(tuple._2.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("Moviesdata"),Bytes.toBytes("MovieSummary"))),
             Bytes.toString(tuple._2.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("Moviesdata"),Bytes.toBytes("MovieActor")))
             )
         })
```

Here, "moviesdata" is the columnfamily of the HBase table and "MovieName"&"MovieSummary" & "MovieActor" are column names. "transformedRDD" in the above snippet is of type RDD[String,String,String]. It has been converted into type RDD[String] by:

```
val arrayRDD: RDD[String] = transformedRDD.map(x => (x._1 + " " + x._2 + " " + x._3))
```

From this, all words have been extracted by doing this:

```
val words = arrayRDD.map(x => x.split(" "))
```

The words which we would are looking for in the HBase Table rows are in a csv file. One of the column, let's say "synonyms" column,  of the csv has the words which we would look for. Another column in the csv is a "target_tag" column, which has the words which would be tagged to the row corresponding to which there is match.
Read the csv by:

```
val csv = sc.textFile("/tag/moviestagdata.csv")
```

reading the synonyms column: (synonyms column is the second column, therefore "p(1)" in the below snippet)

```
val synonyms = csv.map(_.split(",")).map( p=>p(1))
```

reading the target_tag column: (target_tag is the 3rd column)

```
val targettag = csv.map(_.split(",")).map(p=>p(2))
```

Some rows in synonyms and targetag have more than one strings and are seperated by "@@@". The snippet to seperate them is this:

```
val splitsyno = synonyms.map(x => x.split("@@@"))
val splittarget = targettag.map(x=>x.split("@@@"))
```

Now, to match each string from "splitsyno", we need to traverse every row, and further a row might have many strings, hence, to create a set of every string, I did this:(an empty set was created)

```
splitsyno.map(x=>x.foreach(y=>set += y)
```

To match every string with those in "words" created up above, I did this:

```
val check = words.exists(set contains _)
```

Now, the problem which I am facing is that I don't exactly know that strings from what rows in csv are matching to strings from what rows in HBase table. This is needed as I would need to find corresponding target string and which row in HBase table to add to. How should I get it done? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: From Hbase you are getting `words` which is MovieName, MovieSummary and MovieActor, how you are going to match this with CSV file, based on what column you are going to match? basically if you want to match different rdds, you can create it as `key rdd` and use `join` method..

Comment: val check = words.exists(set contains _), this command checks if the strings from "set" are presents in "words" or not. "set" here is an set of all strings in csv which we want to match. Here I can't exactly say string which matches is from what row in csv and hence can't tag. I will look into key rdd and join now.

Comment: @Shankar Is there a way in which if I call map or foreach function, I can keep track of the number of iteration which map/foreach has made so far.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? if you really want to get the matched records, create keyrdd from rdd using `rdd.keyBy` or rdd.map and return as tuple, then you can use the join method to return all the matched rows from both rdds.

Comment: No, not only I have to match but when match happens I have append a corresponding tag in Hbase table. So I need to know strings of which row of csv matched to strings from which row of hbase table.